# How can I get all files from particular folder to datagrid using c# and wpf

Tags: file

view all files with their names,size and date creation From a specific directory in a datagrid inside my c# wpf app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach (string file in fileEntries)
{
    fileList.Add(new FileInfo(file));
}

datagrid.ItemsSource = fileList;
```

Then map FileInfo properties to data column. Check class detail here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks but insted of fileInfo can i use any other class because its getting all information it means DirectoryName,IsReadOnly,LastAccessTime etc

Comment: Use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx to get the data you need. However, I do not think a lot of File.GetXXX looks neat.